# Making Tabs visible only if a value is selected

Tags: android, tabs, spinner

I have a home page which consists of a Spinner. The values in the spinner are populated by Json values.

I have 5 Tabs in the application in which the first tab consists of the Home page itself.

The flow is like this Home Page->Select a Values from Spinner->Then display the Tabs only if a value is selected-> The first page in the Tabs is the Home page again with the Spinner Value selected

Can anyone please help me because i am stuck at displaying tabs only when a item is selected from the spinner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Nested Activities is the way to go for this...

For anyone who might be interested there's a detailed [blog here](http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/) with code which might help some one in need.

Answer (score 0):

The view for the tab labels is a `TabWidget`. In your `TabActivity` try:

```
getTabWidget().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide the tab labels. If you want to hide the tabs labels and the selected tab contents, you want to make the `TabHost` invisible:

```
getTabHost().setVisibility(View.GONE);
```